# CSS extra scrollable white space

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i have a rectangle that contains information it is also made scrollable , I have however noticed extra scrolling white space below the content how is it that i may fix this .
Im not sure if it will show clearly on jsfiddle because i have alot of images:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lezuus/EUKxX/1/

Scrollbox CSS

```
 #rect {
              font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
              text-align: justify;
              width: 917px;
              height: 800px;
              background:white;
              position: relative ;
              left:185px;
              top:100px;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
              -moz-border-radius: 5px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
              -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              overflow:scroll;
              overflow-x:hidden;
              color:#484848;


              }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is it's at least partially related to you using position:relative and manually positioning the contents of your rectangle.  You should be able to just make them all divs with display:block and let the browser lay then out normally.

Comment: When using `position:relative` with offset values (left, top), the element displays at an offset, but occupies space in the page layout as if there were no offset. Only add offset values to `position:relative` if that's what you require, because it confuses the page layout.